# While loop guessing number game python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

So I think I understand why the code is not running past the **while** statement, but I don't know how to get it to recognize the **guess** part of it and run through it. I've searched through several questions on the looping part, but I can't actually see execution of it.

```
num_answer = int(input('What should the answer be? '))
guesses = int(input('How many guesses? '))
answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))

while answer != num_answer and guesses != guesses:
    answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    if answer < num_answer:
       print('The number is higher than that.')
       guesses += 1
       answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    elif answer > num_answer:
       print('The number is lower than that.')
       guesses += 1
       answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    elif answer == num_answer:
       print('You win!')
    elif guesses > guesses and answer != num_answer:
       print("You lose; the number was", num_answer, ".")
```

Comment: Neither `guesses != guesses` nor `guesses > guesses` will ever be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a variable to itself. 
"guesses != guesses"
is always going to return false so your "while" is never going to be run.
You could change you guesses variable into two separate.

```
num_answer = int(input('What should the answer be? '))
guessesMax = int(input('How many guesses? '))
answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))

while answer != num_answer and guessesMax != guessesCount:
    answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    if answer < num_answer:
       print('The number is higher than that.')
       guessesCount += 1
       answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    elif answer > num_answer:
       print('The number is lower than that.')
       guessesCount += 1
       answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    elif answer == num_answer:
       print('You win!')
    elif guessesCount == guessesMax and answer != num_answer:
       print("You lose; the number was", num_answer, ".")
```

Also changed your last elif with a "==". But it is useless because when

```
guessesCount == guessesMax
```

the while will not be executed ;)

EDIT:
You need to add

```
guessesCount = 0
```

On top for it to work.
Also in your while

```
answer = int(input('Guess a number: '))
```

is executing twice, either you put it in the beggining of your loop or in each "if, elif, else" but now in both ;)

Comment: I edited my code to add a different variable to equal `guessesMax`, but I can't get the while loop to end when `guessesCount == guessesMax`